# Android - Scope for access gmail with server

Tags: android, gmail, imap

I want to connect with oAuth2 the IMAP of Google. But the App seems to be not really authorize.

I try using the scope `oauth2:https://mail.google.com/` but the token returned is unusable by the server.

Then I want to set more datas on the scope Android say : "INVALID_SCOPE".

The scope is:

```
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:%s:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s",
                             API_KEY, CLIENT_ID, "https://mail.google.com/");
```

With:
`API KEY`: the API KEY of the Server Application (not the web Application Client Api Key)
`CLIENT_ID`: The Client ID of the Service Account (not the web application)

The full Code is :

```
public static String getToken(final Context context, final Activity activity, final String accountName)
{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            String token = null;

            try
            {
                String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:%s:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", API_KEY, CLIENT_ID, "https://mail.google.com/");
                Log.i("GooglePlusSignupTool", "scope : "+scope);
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountName, scope);
            }
            catch (IOException transientEx)
            {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.e("GoogleSignupTool", transientEx.toString());
            }
            catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e)
            {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                Log.e("GoogleSignupTool", e.toString());
                Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                context.startActivity(recover);//ForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
            }
            catch (GoogleAuthException authEx)
            {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                // assuming you have already verified that
                // Google Play services is installed.
                Log.e("GoogleSignupTool", authEx.toString());
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token)
        {
            Log.i("GoogleSignupTool", "Access token retrieved:" + token);
        }

    };
    task.execute();
    Log.i("GoogleSignupTool", "END");
    return "";
}
```